# Moving Pages folder in Next.js application to src folder

Tags: next.js, absolute-path, module-path

In a `create-next-app` Next.js application, I want to move the `pages` folder in the root directory to a `src` folder. I added a `jsconfig.json` with the code (below), however now I get the error message **"404 | This page could not be found."** Anyone have any insight? (Sorry beginner to web development)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you get when compiling? Note that you don't need to add any configuration to move `pages` inside `src` folder, Next.js will automatically look for it in `src` folder (as long as there's no `pages` folder in the root).

Comment: hey @juliomalves, thanks for the response. Sorry a lot wrong in my initial question, just edited it. So it compiles but I receive a 404 request (404 | This page could not be found). What I did was create a src directory, moved the pages folder into that directory, and then added a jsconfig.js file with the baseUrl set to src. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Nextjs will look for your pages in either the [`/pages`]  or the [`/src/pages`] folder and subfolders. There is nothing to configure in your `jsconfig.json`. 
In what folder did you put your pages' source files?  Also, make sure you delete the folder [`/pages`] if you use [`/src/pages`]. [more info on https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory]

Answer (score 53):

Nextjs by default supports moving `/pages` to `src/` folder.

1. Create a /src folder in the root directory.
2. Delete the `/.next` folder
3. Move `/pages` to the  /src folder
   Remember package.json, `.gitignore` and other config files needs to be in the root directory and should not be moved to the /src folder.

**Once** that is done just run the command `$ npm run dev` or `$ yarn dev` , so you can view it on your localhost.

More: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory

Comment: Thanks for this. Could not figure out why my XProvider components were no longer being seen by their consumers.


Deleting the /.next folder fixed it, I assume there must have been a caching issue.

Comment: Keep in mind if using yarn, `yarn dev` won't work, you need to use `npm run dev` after deleting the `.next` directory

Comment: @Daltron Just tried it with `yarn dev` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 14):

In case you are using NextJS + TailwindCSS, you need to change the following in `tailwind.config.js` after moving files under the `src` directory:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
...
...
```

Comment: This was the issue in my case, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to stop the server and then do `npm run dev`. That solved my problem when I moved things into the src directory and started getting 404 pages.

Answer (score 3):

```
content: [
'./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
'./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
```

],

replace above in case of src

Answer (score 1):

As @Thierry mentioned in the comments, according to the docs "Pages can also be added under src/pages as an alternative to the root pages directory. The src directory is very common in many apps and Next.js supports it by default."

So, src/pages will be ignored if pages is present in the root directory.

More at the official docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory

Answer (score 0):

1. src/pages will be ignored if pages is present in the root directory
2. Update tsconfig.json (if you use Typescript)

> ```
> "paths": {
>   "@/*": ["./src/*"]
> }
> ```

3. Reload **npm run dev**